# Daylight saving time and UTC

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, timezone

Can someone confirm that by using UTC date storage in lists it can cause problems after summer time ends?

I'm in the UK and during the summertime I was in UTC+1.

So when i saved a date field using the default UI on a list which stores this data as UTC, the values were the following:

Input: 2015-10-10 15:00:00
Stored: 2015-10-10 14:00:00
Output: 2015-10-10 15:00:00

Now summertime is over and i'm in UTC+0 again. This field show's a wrong value: 2015-10-10 14:00:00.

Am i missing something, or this is the correct behavior? Dates stored during daylight saving time will always show one hour off after DTS ended?

Answer (score -1):

You are applying the standard-time offset for a date that's in daylight time.  The offset should be tied to the date and time being converted, not to the *current* time.